# If a value is True, unlock a field in the creation view in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

In the view for my `Create` method, I have two values that are dependent on each other - when `IsGate` is selected to be True, then the `Condition` field should be unlocked.

Right now the code looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="IsGate"></label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="IsGate" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Condition"></label>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="Condition" />
</div>
```

Therefore, the output is like below.

[image]

I would like that, when `IsGate` is unchecked, the `Condition` field should be locked - therefore not allowing the user to enter anything.

I am quite a beginner when it comes to the UI part and my only thought was to check with an @if whether the value is `true` or `false`, but I am not sure whether that is possible in realtime, without the value being passed to a model or something.

Would that be possible? If yes, what should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, showing how you can disable or enable textbox when a checkbox changes:

```
<input class="form-control" asp-for="IsGate" 
       onchange="document.getElementById('Condition').disabled = !this.checked;" />
<input class="form-control" asp-for="Condition" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For realtime, you should use javascript take a look at `EventTarget.addEventListener()` method [usage example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp), another way is to use `jquery` which is a javascript library and help to interact with html.